# How to convert an epub file to pdf from the command line?

Tags: terminal, command-line, pdf, epub

I want to convert a few .epub files into .pdf files (no merge, just convert file_1.epub to file_1.pdf, file_2.epub to file_2.pdf, ...) and was wondering if there was a way to streamline the process using the Mac command line.

Heard about the Calibre application but this is not what I am looking for as I want to use the command line.

Comment: The reason people say "use calibre" is because going from a DRM and proprietary format like EPUB to PDF is substantially more than a single line command like "epub2pdf file1.epub file2.pdf". Calibre has a "server" option with a CLI that allow you to do these things, but with all the required libraries behind it.  Have you explored that option?

Comment: See if any of the answers [here](https://askubuntu.com/q/299747/976511) help you.

Comment: @NimeshNeema - The first 3 answers are about Calibre and the very next one is hosted on Softpedia which is a great place to acquire malware.  The next ones are `pandoc` which is closer but more for academic things (bibliographies, citations, etc.) and from what I've read in my cursory look, it doesn't handle DRM.

Comment: Thanks for shedding light. I wasn't aware of these things.

Comment: @NimeshNeema Good catch Nimesh, the first answer there describes a command line solution :-)

Answer (score 12):

Calibre has a command line interface, see [this part of the manual](https://manual.calibre-ebook.com/generated/en/cli-index.html). Basically you should be able to add `/Applications/calibre.app/Contents/MacOS` to your `PATH` (or symlink the binaries there into `/usr/local/bin`) and then run

```
ebook-convert input_file output_file
```

Comment: The commands to create a symlink `ln -s /Applications/calibre.app/Contents/MacOS/ebook-convert /usr/local/bin/ebook-convert`